# Chrome won't display PDFs

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

In Chrome, I can't seem to be able to view PDFs anymore. 
These all display forever-loading (or crashing!) tabs for me, but in Firefox, they whip right up:

- http://buprenorphine.samhsa.gov/TAP_30_Certified.pdf (takes 5 sec, big doc )

How can I view PDFs in Chrome again?

Comment: Which version of Chrome? I've just tried the first link in 5.0.375.99 and it worked OK for me.

Comment: 5.0.375.99 also.

Comment: Oh, I disabled all of my extensions and it works now. Sigh.

Comment: OK - Have you checked to see if there's an update to Adobe Reader?

Comment: Oh hell no, I don't even have that awful thing installed. I'm in the process of extension elimination...

Comment: Thanks for you help @ChrisF I see you on that Gaming proposal. Yeah, you go show them that folks > 25 who's boss!

Comment: I can read OP's file with Chrome 5.0.375.99 on Windows XP, but I have failures with others, e.g. http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~waccgs/v35n1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome needed to be restarted. It wasn't an extension.